# C++14 standard Annex A interpretation

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

1. What are "superset of valid C++ constructs" from Annex A ?
2. Also, any guide which will help you read this grammar in Annex A ?

Annex A quote (donot block quote the following as it messes up the angle brackets):

> This summary of C++ syntax is intended to be an aid to comprehension. It is not an exact statement
>       of the language. In particular, the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C++ constructs.
>       Disambiguation rules (6.8, 7.1, 10.2) must be applied to distinguish expressions from declarations. Further,
>       access control, ambiguity, and type rules must be used to weed out syntactically valid but meaningless
>       constructs.

Comment: _"donot block quote the following as it messes up the angle brackets"_ There weren't any _angle brackets_?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and that is a comment and not an answer because?  /cracks whip

Answer (score 2):

Here is one short example that is valid according to the grammar, but not according to the full language rules:

```
int a[];
struct s;

void main(foo bar)
{
    return (sizeof a) + sizeof (s);
}
```

The primary issue is that the grammar is expressed using context-free productions, but C++ syntactic parse is highly contextual.

Answer (score 0):

If S is a set of elements, a superset is another set X such that each element s in S is also an element of X, but there may be elements x in X that are not elements of S.

As an example, `{1,2,3}` is a set of 3 numbers.  `{1,2,3,4}` is a superset of the first set -- it contains the elements in `{1,2,3}`, but also an extra element `4`.

So the grammar listed in Annex A will match C++, but will also match things that are not valid C++.

It then goes on to list some issues you have to solve "outside of the grammar" -- the disambiguation rules, access control, ambiguity, and type rules.

The quote implies, lightly, that this is a complete set of things you must consider to distinguish valid C++ from things matched by the grammar, but does not explicitly say so.  I am uncertain if this light implication is actually intended or not.